# Kubuntu 22.04 Slow StartUp

Tags: networking, kubuntu, vmware

My laptop has been starting up slowly lately. I checked `stacer` App but couldnt find anything:

[image: Stacer]
[image: stacer]

Then, I ran `systemd-analyze critical-chain` command and this is the output:

```
krillavilla on  master [?] 
systemd-analyze critical-chain
The time when unit became active or started is printed after the "@" character.
The time the unit took to start is printed after the "+" character.

graphical.target @5min 13.791s
└─multi-user.target @5min 13.791s
  └─cups-browsed.service @5min 13.791s
    └─cups.service @5min 13.531s +257ms
      └─network.target @5min 13.480s
        └─NetworkManager.service @2.901s +34ms
          └─network-pre.target @2.877s
            └─ufw.service @1.444s +1.432s
              └─local-fs.target @1.424s
                └─boot-efi.mount @1.343s +75ms
                  └─systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-C682\x2d3748.service @1.321s +20ms
                    └─dev-disk-by\x2duuid-C682\x2d3748.device @1.308s
```

Here is `systemd-analyze blame` output:

```
krillavilla on  master [?] 
systemd-analyze blame         
5min 10.575s networking.service
      3.442s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
      1.978s ifupdown-pre.service
      1.490s udisks2.service
      1.432s snapd.service
      1.432s ufw.service
      1.419s smartmontools.service
       834ms dev-nvme0n1p2.device
       677ms snapd.seeded.service
       558ms systemd-resolved.service
       556ms systemd-timesyncd.service
       300ms ua-timer.service
       287ms tlp.service
       272ms user@1000.service
       257ms cups.service
       256ms modprobe@mtdpstore.service
       247ms vmware-USBArbitrator.service
       233ms modprobe@chromeos_pstore.service
       200ms networkd-dispatcher.service
       181ms systemd-udev-trigger.service
       168ms bluetooth.service
       156ms systemd-logind.service
       152ms qemu-kvm.service
       139ms apparmor.service
       139ms gpu-manager.service
       135ms keyboard-setup.service
       135ms systemd-modules-load.service
       130ms dev-loop11.device
       129ms accounts-daemon.service
       128ms dev-loop12.device
       127ms dev-loop13.device
       125ms e2scrub_reap.service
       124ms dev-loop16.device
       123ms dev-loop15.device
       122ms dev-loop14.device
       120ms apport.service
       120ms update-notifier-download.service
       119ms dev-loop10.device
       119ms dev-loop8.device
       118ms dev-loop7.device
       118ms systemd-journald.service
       117ms dev-loop3.device
       117ms dev-loop17.device
       116ms dev-loop9.device
       115ms dev-loop4.device
       114ms dev-loop5.device
       112ms upower.service
       112ms dev-loop6.device
       105ms dev-loop0.device
       100ms avahi-daemon.service
        96ms systemd-udevd.service
        93ms grub-common.service
        85ms lm-sensors.service
        84ms ModemManager.service
        78ms alsa-restore.service
        78ms preload.service
        76ms snapd.apparmor.service
        76ms iio-sensor-proxy.service
        75ms boot-efi.mount
        74ms secureboot-db.service
        72ms plymouth-quit.service
        71ms dev-hugepages.mount
        70ms dev-mqueue.mount
        69ms polkit.service
        67ms sys-kernel-debug.mount
        65ms sys-kernel-tracing.mount
        62ms clamav-daemon.service
        56ms kmod-static-nodes.service
        54ms modprobe@drm.service
        53ms modprobe@configfs.service
        53ms rsyslog.service
        52ms modprobe@fuse.service
        52ms thermald.service
        49ms ssh.service
        46ms packagekit.service
        43ms snap-bare-5.mount
        42ms run-qemu.mount
        41ms wpa_supplicant.service
        39ms snap-core-13425.mount
        38ms snap-core18-2409.mount
        37ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service
        36ms snap-core18-2538.mount
        35ms snap-core20-1593.mount
        34ms nvidia-persistenced.service
        34ms NetworkManager.service
        34ms kerneloops.service
        33ms snap-core20-1611.mount
        31ms snap-firefox-1635.mount
        30ms systemd-remount-fs.service
        30ms snap-firefox-1670.mount
        28ms snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d28\x2d1804-161.mount
        26ms snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d38\x2d2004-106.mount
        26ms plymouth-start.service
        25ms snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d38\x2d2004-112.mount
        23ms snap-gtk\x2dcommon\x2dthemes-1534.mount
        22ms snap-gtk\x2dcommon\x2dthemes-1535.mount
        21ms console-setup.service
        20ms plymouth-read-write.service
        20ms snap-masscode-x1.mount
        20ms systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-C682\x2d3748.service
        18ms snap-snapd-16010.mount
        17ms snap-snapd-16292.mount
        16ms grub-initrd-fallback.service
        15ms user-runtime-dir@1000.service
        15ms systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service
        14ms colord.service
        13ms systemd-random-seed.service
        12ms systemd-sysusers.service
        11ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service
        10ms systemd-sysctl.service
        10ms systemd-user-sessions.service
         9ms sddm.service
         8ms systemd-backlight@backlight:intel_backlight.service
         8ms modprobe@efi_pstore.service
         6ms systemd-update-utmp.service
         6ms systemd-update-utmp-runlevel.service
         5ms rtkit-daemon.service
         5ms modprobe@pstore_blk.service
         5ms setvtrgb.service
         4ms systemd-journal-flush.service
         4ms modprobe@pstore_zone.service
         3ms sys-fs-fuse-connections.mount
         3ms modprobe@ramoops.service
         2ms sys-kernel-config.mount
         1ms snapd.socket
```

Last night, I was messing with my network interfaces `sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces`
because my VMWare Workstation Pro Virtual Machine was keep getting disconnect when I choose NAT connectivity:

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
# Include files from /etc/network/interfaces.d:
source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
post-up iwconfig wlan0 power off
post-up iwconfig wlan1 power off
```

The VMWare Workstation issue is not as pressing as Slow startup.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out my issue. When I added `auto eth0` to my interfaces file `nano /etc/network/interfaces`, the NetworkManager services were cycling my eth0 interface which held up my boot time.

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
# Include files from /etc/network/interfaces.d:
source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto eth0
allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
post-up iwconfig wlan0 power off
post-up iwconfig wlan1 power off
```

I removed `auto eth0` and my laptop boot up fine.